# Не получается перевести строку в байты

Tags: python, кодировка, utf-8, base64

Я зашифровал слово с помошью библиотеки pyaes, получился такой набор байтов - b'\xdfm\xfdsw\xdc?\x8f\xb00\xb5%\x13\x03\x1d\x11Gf\xc0l\x00\x99s\xd2\xf2\xb4\x16]\x08\xbe\xd5\xd6\xb8\x81\x84\xdbN\x81\x17V\xa5\xa4\xc4\x0b\xe0\xa0\x08\x97\xbfc\xa3b2\xe2q?[=\xc2*.Y@\xe6\xbc\x99o\xc25\xf3\xc4\xa7\xca\&\xc2tOh(H7\x89'

По задумке пользователь должен скопировать данный текст и потом вставить в дешифровщик, но при вводе это уже будет строка, при попытке сделать опять в байты получается вот так - b"b'\xdfm\xfdsw\xdc?\x8f\xb00\xb5%\x13\x03\x1d\x11Gf\xc0l\x00\x99s\xd2\xf2\xb4\x16]\x08\xbe\xd5\xd6\xb8\x81\x84\xdbN\x81\x17V\xa5\xa4\xc4\x0b\xe0\xa0\x08\x97\xbfc\xa3b2\xe2q?[=\xc2*.Y@\xe6\xbc\x99o\xc25\xf3\xc4\xa7\xca\\&\xc2tOh(H7\x89'"

как можно это исправить?
я использую .encode('utf-8')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отрезать обрамление и закодировать в `latin-1`.

```
s = "b'\xdfm\xfdsw\xdc?\x8f\xb00\xb5%\x13\x03\x1d\x11Gf\xc0l\x00\x99s\xd2\xf2\xb4\x16]\x08\xbe\xd5\xd6\xb8\x81\x84\xdbN\x81\x17V\xa5\xa4\xc4\x0b\xe0\xa0\x08\x97\xbfc\xa3b2\xe2q?[=\xc2*.Y@\xe6\xbc\x99o\xc25\xf3\xc4\xa7\xca\&\xc2tOh(H7\x89'"

result = s[2:-1].encode('latin-1')
```

Но вообще будет проще, если пользователю выдавать hex-строку (`bytes(...).hex()`), а при вводе делать обратное преобразование (`bytes.fromhex()`).

Comment: спасибо, большое, попробовал с преобразованием hex, мало того что работает, так и выглядит лучше чем просто байты)